# Android Firebase addOnChildListener Fatal Exception "print-in needs message" and No setter/field

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I believe I have everything setup correctly, in fact, it even works! I get results in the log until it crashes.

I really don't understand what's going on.

In the database:

```
    messages
    ......body
    ......name
    ......msgId
    ......createdat
    ......receiverUid
    ......senderUid
```

My class:

```
public class Message {
    public String msgId;
    public String receiverUid;
    public String senderUid;
    public String body;
    public String name;
    public Long createdat;

    public Message(){

    }

    public Message(String msgId, String receiverUid, String senderUid, String body, String name, Long createdat){
        this.msgId = msgId;
        this.receiverUid = receiverUid;
        this.senderUid = senderUid;
        this.body = body;
        this.name = name;
        this.createdat = createdat;
    }
}
```

The line that gives the error:

```
Log.d("childadded ", newMessage.body);
```

The entire command:

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {

            Message newMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
            messageList.add(newMessage);
            //moonList.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Memf.class));
            mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d("childadded ", newMessage.body);
        }
```

And the results:

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
D/childadded: vatican
D/childadded: gastro
    dangers of Skynet
D/childadded: stay so
    amazing
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for BMsZWfn7y6RceZGJeSNBbCpPmkm1 found on class com.thisapp.Message
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dhienterprises.dhawkins.nofltr, PID: 19325
    java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

As you can see, it's returning some of the results but skipping some of the "Childadded" entries.

Also the fact that it's saying there's no field for that username is WEIRD. as you can see there's ABSOLUTELY a field for receiverUid. I'm not really understanding the problem.

Why would it work just fine and then crash?

**UPDATE** Added "getters" for my class... Still wasn't working. Error message was exactly the same. Turns out the TRUE cause for the error was just some malformed object in my database. (This is why all the other objects imported just fine.) Deleted the offending object, now everything works.

Accepting the answer given because it's great to know you can setup getters and setters for an entire class with the press of just two buttons!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You getter-setters are missing

When using `.getValue()`, note that:

> This method is used to marshall the data contained in this snapshot
>   into a class of your choosing. The class must fit 2 simple
>   constraints:
>
> 1. The class must have a default constructor that takes no arguments
> 2. The class must define public getters for the properties to be assigned. Properties without a public getter will be set to their
>      default value when an instance is deserialized

***I suggest that after defining the class variable just do `Alt+Insert` (`Command+N` for Mac) in Android Studio to generate the public getters-setters.***

Your class should ideally look like:

```
 class Message {
     private String author;
     private String text;

     private Message() {}

     public Message(String author, String text) {
         this.author = author;
         this.text = text;
     }

     public String getAuthor() {
         return author;
     }

     public String getText() {
         return text;
     }
 }


 // Later
 Message m = snapshot.getValue(Message.class);
```

Reference : [DataSnapshot](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getValue(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E))

Comment: What's Alt+Insert on like a Mac keyboard? (There is no "Insert" button...)

Comment: You don't actually need getters and setters beyond what I have for this. The problem turned out to be just some badly formed objects in my database. Deleted the offending object and the original code that I have works fine.